# Explanation for the given code output in C

Tags: c, character-encoding, char, output

I have written code in C as

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a = 128;
    char b = -128;
    printf("%c",a);
    printf("%c",b);
}
```

The output of above code is ÇÇ
Using 128 or -128 output is coming out to be same. Why? Please explain using binary if possible.

Comment: One of `{-128, 128}` is outside the range of 8-bit [2's complement](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=wikipedia+2s+complement&atb=v1-1&ia=web) `char`. If `char` is signed, range is `-128` to `127`... if it is `unsigned`, range is `0` to `255`. To be on the safe side, always keep your chars between `0` and `127`. Explicitly use `signed char` or `unsigned char` if you require those ranges.

Answer (score 3):

A signed `char` type typically has a range of -128 to 127.  Since 128 is outside of this range, your compiler is converting it to a value with the same 8-bit bit pattern, and this is -128.

Comment: Confirm not **UB** in C ... see [C11 6.3.1.3p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3) ... it's implementation defined

Comment: And if `char` is `unsigned`?  Whether or not unqualified `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation dependent (an can usually be defined by compiler option).  It that case it is the -128 that is invalid and is coerced to 128.

Comment: @Clifford signed is much more likely, but the answer doesn't change either way - as long as it's two's complement 128 and -128 will have the same bit pattern in the lower 8 bits.

Comment: @MarkRansom The result does not change, but your answer was very specifically about signed.  Somewhat pedantic I agree, but the answer must change if it were to include unsigned, because whilst the result is the same, your arguments as to why do not apply.

Comment: @Clifford I have yet to see a compiler that doesn't default to signed char unless you go out of your way to specify it with a compiler option.  So I wrote the answer that I thought was 99.9% likely to apply.  I was going to invite you to write your own, but I see that you already have.

Comment: Implementations on x86 do indeed largely use signed char. On ARM however unsigned is more common. I am an embedded systems developer, mostly working in ARM, so from my point of view it is the reverse. Not as uncommon as you might think. https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0013/d/Porting/Miscellaneous-C-porting-issues/unsigned-char-and-signed-char

Answer (score 2):

The literal -128 has type `int` and on a 32bit 2's complement representation has the bit pattern:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0000
```

In this case, when you assign it to a `char` there is an implicit conversion (cast) such that only the LSB is used `1000 000` or in decimal, 128.  Hence the result is the same.

Strictly the behaviour is implementation defined if `char` is `signed`, and the standard defines the behaviour in somewhat arcane "*as-if*" terms for `unsigned char`.  Whether `char` itself is signed or unsigned is itself implementation defined as is the actual width and therefore range of a `char`.  In practice though the above explanation is what is happening in this case and is the most likely behaviour for any implementation with 8-bit `char`, it makes no difference whether `char` is signed or unsigned.